# How to show a div onclick with a button inside a v-for loop in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, if-statement, vuejs2

**Background**

I have a v-for loop that contains a pair of buttons and inputs. The buttons contains an @click event that is suppose to show the corresponding input.

**Problem**

When the buttons are clicked it shows all the input instances instead of the corresponding input to the button clicked.

```
 <div class="buttonFor my-3" v-for="(expense,index) in expenseButton" :key="index">
            <input type="submit" @click="showInput(expense)" :value="expense.expensesKey" />
            <input v-show="needEdit" v-model.number="expense.subExpense" type="number" />
          </div>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [],
      needEdit: false
    };
  }
```

```
methods: {

    showInput() {
      this.needEdit = !this.needEdit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better you keep track of the chosen id. you could edit your data to receive chosen id like:

```
data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [],
      chosenExpenseId: null
    };
}
```

your show input receives the index instead:

```
methods: {
    showInput(index) {
      this.chosenExpenseId = index;
      // if want to make the button to hide input once clicked back
      // this.chosenExpenseId = this.chosenExpenseId !== index ? index : null;
    }
}
```

at your template you pass the index and validates input show condition as:

```
<input type="submit" @click="showInput(index)" :value="expense.expensesKey" />
<input v-show="index === chosenExpenseId" v-model.number="expense.subExpense" type="number" />
```

Comment: Appreciate it man! I been trying to get better at finding solutions